How to fix a GitHub error: "Cannot update this protected ref" when pushing to a public repository as an owner
I created a private repository at GitHub, but now decided that I want it to be public. I changed it to public via GitHub settings, and havent changed anything else. I work with Visual Studio. When I wanted to push a local commit to the repository it failed and produced the following console output:
Remote: Error: GH013: Repository rule violations found for refs/heads/main.        
Remote: Review all repository rules at http://github.com/xxx/xxx/rules?ref=refs%2Fheads%2Fmain        
Remote: 
Remote: - Cannot update this protected ref.        
Remote: 
To https://github.com/xxx/xxx
Error: main -> main (push declined due to repository rule violations)
failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxx/xxx'

I tried pushing it manually via Git Bash, but it produced the same error. I am signed in with GitHub in Visual Studio. I also the owner of the repository, and there are no collaborators. I haven't added any custom rules or roles in the GitHub repository.

Never encountered this sort of issue before, but my hunch is that because the permissions have changed since the initial checkout, this will prevent you pushing to it.
Try cloning from the public repo and push to it. Should work.

I managed to work around it by going on the GitHub repo page -> Settings -> Rulesets -> General (created by default) -> Bypass list -> and added 'Repository admin' role to the list. It works, but I'm not sure if it's the correct way. Shouldn't repo Owners bypass all rulesets by default? Isn't Repository admin a different role from Owners?
